# I have a problem with converting pdf to img using drupal 7 module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

DRUPAL 7
I have no experience with Drupal , but i need to make it works...
Trying to work with pdf_to_image module.
Im following README.txt that says:

```
=== Manual configuration ===

- First, add an image field on your chosen content type. This is where the
  generated images will be stored.
- Set the allowed fields to 1 if you just want a cover page, direct number to
  store only some count of pages or 'unlimited' if you want all pages
  to be generated.
- Next add a filefield to your chosen content type and choose
  'PDF to Image' as the widget.
  This filefield should be configured to only accept PDF file types.
- When configuring this field, you will be required to link the uploaded file
  field with the target image field.
- You can add image style handling to the image field rendering as normal to
  adjust the size of the results and how they display on the page.
```

But to be honest i dont even know where to start with the first step. Is there like any tutorial or maybe similar post that i can look up to?

PDF File is imported from a server and i need to convert every page to img and display on website

**Edit**
So i've checked '/admin/reports/status' and it says that in bright green color:

```
OK - Imagemagick support for PDF to Image
```

How should i link file field with image field?

```
- When configuring this field, you will be required to link the uploaded file
field with the target image field.
```

Comment: First you need to verify if requierements are installed on your environnement , check this out  :  https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/InternetDevels.com/1415404

Module need ImageMagick and Php extensions to be installed to work properly

Comment: Im sure that i have all modules installed, but i do not have access to server/terminal. Can i somehow check if ImageMagick is installed on server?

Comment: @Fky Is it possible, that i might have somehow wrong cron settings for PDF to IMG module?